# How do I set range in forloop in Django template tags?

Tags: django

So I want to create a for loop that has certain range. Let me show you the code. 
views.py

```
def mainPage(request):
    ...
    myList = [ ### has some elements ### ]
    listLength = len(myList)

    context = {'listLength' : listLength}
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

main.html

```
{% for i in listLength %}
<div class="book-{{i}}">Book number {{i}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

So I know that the `{% for i in listLength %}` part is wrong. I want to pass each number from 1 to `listLength`, but can't figure out how. Please help. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `range` object to the template instead:

```
def mainPage(request):
    # …
    myList = [  ]
    listLength = len(myList)

    context = {'listLength' : range(1, listLength+1)}
    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```